# BigQuery Standart SQL: extract day-of-week name from timestamp

Tags: sql, timestamp, google-bigquery, dayofweek

I'm Using BigQuery **Standart SQL.**

I need to convert a timestamp to Day-of-week name.

e.g. convert today's timestamp (2016-11-24 00:00:00) into a string: 'Thursday'

Thanks :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  CURRENT_DATE() AS day,
  FORMAT_DATE('%a', CURRENT_DATE()) AS weekday_name_abbreviated,
  FORMAT_DATE('%A', CURRENT_DATE()) AS weekday_name_full
```

or

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  DATE('2016-11-24 00:00:00') AS day,
  FORMAT_DATE('%a', DATE('2016-11-24 00:00:00')) AS weekday_name_abbreviated,
  FORMAT_DATE('%A', DATE('2016-11-24 00:00:00')) AS weekday_name_full
```

result is

```sql
day         weekday_name_abbreviated    weekday_name_full    
2016-11-24  Thu                         Thursday
```

Answer (score 8):

In BigQuery you can use:

```
SELECT

EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK
  FROM
    {your_timestamp}) AS dayofweek,

FROM TABLE
```

It returns an integer: 1 = Sunday, 7 = Saturday

Comment: > DAYOFWEEK: Returns values in the range [1,7] with Sunday as the first day of of the week.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/timestamp_functions#extract

Answer (score 0):

You have to use DAYOFWEEK() and then a CASE statement to return day of week.  DAYOFWEEK() returns the day of the week as an integer between 1 (Sunday) and 7 (Saturday).  [Date and time functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/legacy-sql)

e.g.

```
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE()) = 1 THEN 'Sunday'
    WHEN DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE()) = 2 THEN 'Monday'
    WHEN DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE()) = 3 THEN 'Tuesday'
    WHEN DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE()) = 4 THEN 'Wednesday'
    WHEN DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE()) = 5 THEN 'Thursday'
    WHEN DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE()) = 6 THEN 'Friday'
    WHEN DAYOFWEEK(CURRENT_DATE()) = 7 THEN 'Saturday'
  END Weekday
```

Comment: Yep i figured this way already. It works but looks pretty ugly :P

Thanks anyway!

Comment: @mav3n - this **DOES NOT** work for BigQuery Standard SQL. you should correct your Edit to this answer

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant : Standard SQL have backward compatibility to Legacy SQL right?

Comment: @mav3n - nope - no backward compatibility!